# Simple java why variable doesn't change?

Tags: java

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int lowest= 5;
        int sum = 2;
        if (lowest>sum){
            sum=lowest; 
        }
        System.out.println( lowest );
    }   
}
```

From this code I, get 5 but shouldn't I get 2? how should I change the code to make it equal to 2 instead of "sum=lowest;"?

Comment: Assignment is right to left.

Comment: "a = b" will assign value of "b" to "a", not value of "a" to "b"...

Answer (score 3):

Because assignment is the other way around. It is like:

```
variable = new value;
```

So, you want:

```
lowest = sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you never alter the value of `lowest`, but you assign `lowest` to `sum`

Do you mena to print the value of `sum` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (lowest > sum){
    sum = lowest; 
}
```

to

```
if (lowest > sum){
    lowest = sum; 
}
```

if you are trying to get lowest to be equal to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `2`, just do:

```
    if (lowest>sum){
        lowest=sum; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lowest = sum.

by doing "sum = lowest" you are assigning the value of lowest to sum. Assignments work right to left